# Angular 14 typed FormArray Object is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, formarray

Attempt to implement a typed form. I have formArray  prices if i set UntypedFormArray this works. But else i set prices model: FormArray<FormGroup>; I have Error in HTML {{form.value.prices[i]?.price}}.
Operator "?" Does not help. If I specify the type.
I need to add some logic to display percentage values to the user. But when outputting a variable, an error occurs. I don't understand why. I've been stuck with this error for two days now.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUOcI.png)

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Xyrn.png)

Model:

```
export interface ProductFormModel {
    id?: FormControl<id | null>;
    productId?: FormControl<id | null>;
    sku?: FormControl<string | null>;
    prices: FormArray<FormGroup<PriceFormModel>>;
    // prices: UntypedFormArray;
    stockSellerPercent: FormControl<number | null>;
    shopTax: FormControl<number | null>;
    titleRU: FormControl<string | null>;
    titleUA: FormControl<string | null>;
    descriptionRU: FormControl<string | null>;
    descriptionUA: FormControl<string | null>;
    smallDescriptionRU: FormControl<string | null>;
    smallDescriptionUA: FormControl<string | null>;
    bestSeller: FormControl<boolean | null>;
    hotSeller: FormControl<boolean | null>;
    productCategoryId: FormControl<id | null>;
    filters: UntypedFormArray;
    photos?: FormControl<any>;
    stockSeller: FormControl<boolean | null>;
    brandId: FormControl<id | null>;
    productStatus: FormControl<ProductStatusEnum | null>;}
```

Model element form array prices:

```
export interface PriceFormModel {
    id: FormControl<id | null>;
    price: FormControl<number | null>;
    minQuantity: FormControl<number | null>;
```

}

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-add-new-item',
    templateUrl: './add-product.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./add-product.component.scss'],

})

export class AddProductComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentChecked {
        public form!: FormGroup<ProductFormModel>;
        public acceptedId: id = '';
        public activateFileUpload = true;
        public titleUACtrl!: FormControl<string | null>;
        public titleRUCtrl!: FormControl<string | null>;
        public smallDescriptionUACtrl!: FormControl<string | null>;
        public smallDescriptionRUCtrl!: FormControl<string | null>;
        public descriptionRUCtrl!: FormControl<string | null>;
        public descriptionUACtrl!: FormControl<string | null>;
        public bestSellerCtrl!: FormControl<boolean | null>;
        public stockSellerCtrl!: FormControl<boolean | null>;
        public stockSellerPercentCtrl!: FormControl<number | null>;
        public hotSellerCtrl!: FormControl<boolean | null>;
        public shopTaxCtrl!: FormControl<number>;
        public productCategoryIdCtrl!: FormControl<id | null>;
        public brandCtrl!: FormControl<id | null>;
        public productStatusCtrl!: FormControl<ProductStatusEnum | null>;
        public shopTax = OPTIONS_SHOP_TAX;
        public submitted!: any;
        public value!: any;
        public optionsStockSellerPercent = OPTIONS_STOCK_SELLER_PERCENT;
        public isDisabledStockSellerPercent = true;
        public productStatuses: Array<productStatusModel> = PRODUCT_STATUSES_OPTIONS;

        constructor(
                private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
                private productServ: ProductService,
                private messageService: MessageService,
                private support: SupportService,
                private spinner: NgxSpinnerService,
                private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
        ) {
                this.createControls();
                this.createForm();
        }

        get f(): any {
                return this.form.controls;
        }

        get prices(): FormArray<FormGroup<PriceFormModel>> {
                return this.form.get('prices') as FormArray<FormGroup<PriceFormModel>>;
        }


        get filters(): UntypedFormArray {
                return this.form.get('filters') as UntypedFormArray;
        }

        ngOnInit(): void {
        }

        ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
                this.cdr.detectChanges();
        }
        
        private createControls(): void {
                this.titleUACtrl = new FormControl<string | null>(null, [Validators.required]);
                this.titleRUCtrl = new FormControl<string | null>(null, [Validators.required]);
                this.productCategoryIdCtrl = new FormControl<id | null>(null, [Validators.required]);
                this.smallDescriptionRUCtrl = new FormControl<string | null>(null, [Validators.required]);
                this.smallDescriptionUACtrl = new FormControl<string | null>(null, [Validators.required]);
                this.descriptionRUCtrl = new FormControl<string | null>(null, [Validators.required]);
                this.descriptionUACtrl = new FormControl<string | null>(null, [Validators.required]);
                this.bestSellerCtrl = new FormControl<boolean | null>(false, [Validators.required]);
                this.stockSellerCtrl = new FormControl<boolean | null>(false, [Validators.required]);
                this.stockSellerPercentCtrl = new FormControl<number>({
                        value: 0,
                        disabled: this.isDisabledStockSellerPercent,
                }, {nonNullable: true});
                this.hotSellerCtrl = new FormControl<boolean>(false, {nonNullable: true});
                this.shopTaxCtrl = new FormControl<number>(10, {nonNullable: true});
                this.brandCtrl = new FormControl<id | null>(null, [Validators.required]);
                this.productStatusCtrl = new FormControl<ProductStatusEnum | null>(null, [Validators.required]);
        }

        private createForm(): void {
                this.form = this.formBuilder.group<ProductFormModel>({
                        id: new FormControl<id | null>(null),
                        productStatus: this.productStatusCtrl,
                        stockSellerPercent: this.stockSellerPercentCtrl,
                        shopTax: this.shopTaxCtrl,
                        titleUA: this.titleUACtrl,
                        titleRU: this.titleRUCtrl,
                        productCategoryId: this.productCategoryIdCtrl,
                        smallDescriptionRU: this.smallDescriptionRUCtrl,
                        smallDescriptionUA: this.smallDescriptionUACtrl,
                        descriptionRU: this.descriptionRUCtrl,
                        descriptionUA: this.descriptionUACtrl,
                        prices: this.formBuilder.array([
                                this.formBuilder.group<PriceFormModel>({
                                        id: new FormControl<id | null>(null),
                                        price: new FormControl<number | null >(null, [Validators.required]),
                                        minQuantity: new FormControl<number | null>(1, [Validators.required])
                                }),
                        ]),
                        bestSeller: this.bestSellerCtrl,
                        stockSeller: this.stockSellerCtrl,
                        hotSeller: this.hotSellerCtrl,
                        brandId: this.brandCtrl,
                        filters: this.formBuilder.array([]),
                });
                console.log(this.form);
        }


        public addNewEl(): void {
                this.prices.push(this.formBuilder.group<PriceFormModel>({
                        id: new FormControl<id | null>(null),
                        price: new FormControl<number | null>(null, [Validators.required]),
                        minQuantity: new FormControl<number | null>(null, [Validators.required]),
                }));
        }
```

Comment: can you tell if `StrictNullChecks` is set to true  in the `tsconfig` or not? - Did you try tell `TypeScript` that you are awre this property will be undefined but it will recieve value at runtime by adding the assertion "`!`" mark  to your property declaration like so:    `prices!: FormArray<FormGroup<PriceFormModel>>;`

Comment: @Walid 
 StrictNullChecks - absent at all. 
Set "!" in interfacce call error(
TS1131: Property or signature expected.
TS2304: Cannot find name 'prices'.)

Comment: the assertion is supposed to be in the component not in the interface

Comment: interfaces are ignored at runtime - They are compile time only

Comment: @Walid yes but i am using get on formarray and they are conflicting. For the sake of interest, I tried to comment. To add public properties to a class. But it did not help. Same error.

Comment: Solution options.
1. Replace the property in the config with "strictNullChecks": false,
2. Add check for everything *ngIf="this.form && this.form.value && this.form.value.prices && this.form.value.prices[i] && this.form.value.prices[i].price"
3. Move the logic into a function and do all the checks there. 

But I don't know, the first option is the easiest. But somehow not correct logically. So, as it allows errors in the code in the future. The second and third are too big. And the error is not related to Angular and Forms, but more to Typescript version updates

Comment: 3. HTML: {{viewPrice(i)}}
TS:
public viewPrice(i: number): number | null | undefined {
                if (this.form && this.form.value && this.form.value.prices && this.form.value.prices[i] && this.form.value.prices[i].price) {
                                return this.form.value.prices[i].price;
                }
                return null;
        }